# No initscrip name console - CX_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I have been trying to get cx_freeze working on ubuntu, but when i try to run the "python setup.py build" i get the following error:
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no initscript named Console

I have searched google and i see a lot of people have ahd this issue, but i can't seem to find a solution.

my setup.py code is as follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


setup( name = "hello world" ,
   version = "0.1" ,
   description = "Hello" ,
   executables = [Executable("hello.py")] ,
   )
```

I have placed the setup.py file and hello.py in the same folder. 
Any idea as to what could solve this problem?

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    executables = [Executable("hello.py")] ,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg    
  cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 365, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build.py", line 128, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
  /cx_Freeze/dist.py", line 234, in run
    metadata = metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
  /cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 466, in _VerifyConfiguration
    self._GetInitScriptFileName()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
/cx_Freeze/freezer.py", line 311, in _GetInitScriptFileName
    raise ConfigError("no initscript named %s", name)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no initscript named Console
```

Comment: Looks like cx_Freeze hasn't got installed completely. `Console.py` should be in `.../cx_Freeze/initscripts/`.

Answer (score 3):

For my installation I took same problem. Looks like symbolic link for initscripts not created, so I make it manually and everything works (change cx_Freeze version to your own):

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
cd cx_Freeze-4.3.1-py2.7-linux-i686.egg
sudo ln -s -t cx_Freeze/ ../../cx_Freeze/initscripts/
```

PS: Ubuntu 12.10/quantal, Python 2.7.3